# how to check if XML element exists or not?

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmlnodelist

I would like to scan my xml file whether the specific node is exists or not
these are my codes

```
 Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
        xmlDoc.Load("C:\Users\Desktop\XMLFILE.xml")

        Dim rootName As String = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.Name
        Dim nodes As XmlNode
        'Dim objTest As XmlElement

        Try
            nodes = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(rootName & "\\PRODUCT\\NAME")
            MessageBox.Show("Exists")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Not exists")
        End Try
```

The results shows "Not Exists".
After I comment out my Try, Catch and End Try, the error results shows:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XPath.XPathException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: 'RootName\\PRODUCT\\NAME' has an invalid token.
```

What does that mean?

Comment: 1) Where is the code with the text "Failed" in it? 2) `nodes` should be `Nothing` if the node wasn't found - it should not raise an exception for that.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the double-backslash with single-forward slash?

Comment: @AndrewMorton sorry, It was supposed to be "Not Exists" instead of "Failed". I edited that part already. In my case, it returns "Not exists" every time the code runs which makes me wonder, does my code for "Exists" incorrect..

Comment: I've tried that one, still it popped out "Not Exists" message. @ajakblackgoat

Comment: Ive tried that and check out my latest edited questions. @AndrewMorton

Comment: @lara You could use a utility like [Xpath generator](https://xmltoolbox.appspot.com/xpath_generator.html) to get the xpath you need, or at least a very good starting point.

Comment: I tried the suggestion by ajakblackgoat by using single forward slash, and it works. The success messages displayed. @AndrewMorton but now, when I deleted the <PRODUCT> tag, the "not exists" message does not displayed. it says "XmlException was unhandled" instead.

Comment: @lara Does the exception happen on the line with SelectSingleNode or somewhere else? I ask because the documentation for the [XmlNode.SelectSingleNode Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode?view=netframework-4.8) says that it returns `Nothing` (`null`) if the node is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all, the path is incorrect. `/` is the path separator for xml path, not `\\`.
2. You should not specify the `rootName` in the xml path since you already calling the `SelectSingleNode` function for the root node (`xmlDoc.DocumentElement`)
3. The way you identify non-existence node incorrect. `SelectSingleNode` does not throw an exception if the path does not exist. Instead, it simply returns `Nothing`.

Based on the above, here are the modified code :

```
Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
xmlDoc.Load("C:\Users\Desktop\XMLFILE.xml")

Dim nodes As XmlNode

Try
    nodes = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("PRODUCT/NAME")

    If nodes Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Not exists")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Exists")
    End If

Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

End Try
```

To use the `SelectSingleNode` from the root, use the following path :

```
xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("descendant::PRODUCT/NAME")
```

Comment: It works perfectly! may I know why I cannot use ` Dim rootName As String = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.Name` ? I'm new to this so I'm a bit blur regarding this topic. What's the difference between SelectSingleNode and SelectNode?

Comment: @lara regarding your first question, please refer to #2 in my answer above.For the 2nd, refer to the documentation : [`SelectSingleNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode) and [`SelectNodes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes)

Comment: it says `SelectNodes` Selects a list of nodes. and `SelectSingleNode` selects the first of element.  what's the difference between these two? I'm still confused @ajakblackgoat

Comment: I know this is old, but for anyone else looking: 
`SelectNodes` is plural and selects all the nodes it finds meeting your criteria. (List of Nodes). 
`SelectSingleNode` is singular and will select only the first one that it finds matching your criteria. 
AFAIK